# IntelliJ IDEA doesn't start on my Windows machine

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-13

This morning when I was trying to load IntellJ it doesn't boot up. I see idea.exe under process tab. When I tried to run idea.bat from command line, I get the following:

> Invalid Log Path: Log path 'Ç:\Users\NAME.IdeaIC2016.3\system\log' is inaccessible. If you have modified the idea.log.path property please make sure it is correct otherwise please re-install the IDE.

Comment: What has this got to do with Eclipse?

Comment: or Java ? i think you should reinstall as the error message suggests

Comment: Is the drive letter really Ç?

Comment: Did you [modify](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207240985) `idea.properties` file? Or did you change the user home environment somehow? It could be that there is a typo, make sure it's using `C:`  drive instead of `Ç:`.

Comment: This can be put on hold under the following standard close reason: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Answer (score 0):

> Check folder permissions, it may be owned by admin for some reason. Try removing this folder so that IDEA creates it again.
>
> Run disk tool with permissions fix.

Taken from:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206156759-IntelliJ-IDEA-14-1-1-on-Mac-OSX-Log-path-Users-username-Library-Logs-IdeaIC14-is-inaccessible-